# Unable to launch multiple programs via a batch file

Tags: batch-file, influxdb, grafana

Am trying to create a batch file, that would launch multiple programs. But unfortunately, things don't seem to work.

Kindly, find below my requirement:

1. Open InfluxDB server
2. Launch Grafana application.

Commands used in the batch:

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Users\C51539A\Downloads\influxdb-1.5.2-1"
Start.cmd
timeout 5
cd "C:\Users\C51539A\Downloads\grafana-5.1.3\bin"
grafana-server.exe
```

The above script, launches InfluxDB. But doesn't moves further.

Could you please suggest me, on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Users\C51539A\Downloads\influxdb-1.5.2-1"
start InfluxDB
ping -n 6 127.0.0.1 > nul
cd "C:\Users\C51539A\Downloads\grafana-5.1.3\bin"
start grafana-server
```

Edit the "start InfluxDB" and "start grafana-server" to be the correct exe names, without .exe

Comment: Thank you very much Luka !! Appreciate your support.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`call`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc732835%28v%3dws.11%29) keyword to have control returned to the caller after invoking another batch script:

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Users\C51539A\Downloads\influxdb-1.5.2-1"
call start.cmd
...
```

Should `start.cmd` run InfluxDB synchronously (i.e. not in the background) you need to launch it in a separate window:

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Users\C51539A\Downloads\influxdb-1.5.2-1"
start "InfluxDB" cmd /c start.cmd
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: By "synchronously" I think you meant to say executing in parallel, Otherwise `start` runs the passed command **A**synchronously. (non-blocking procedure).

Comment: @sst I meant exactly what I wrote. The `start` *command* would be needed for running the `start.cmd` *batch file* asynchronously only if the batch file launches InfluxDB *synchronously* (returning only *after* InfluxDB terminates).

Comment: I see, My eyes just jumped over `.cmd` in `start.cmd` and read it as `start` so I was thinking you are referring to the behavior of `start` command. My mistake, sorry.